# VisualSVN Server responds to all https requests on our server - how to disable?

Tags: svn, iis-7, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

We are hosing several sites on this one Windows 2008 server through IIS7, which also has Visual SVN installed.  Going to https://[any site on the server] brings up the SubVersion Repositories login page.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

All hosted on the same IP address

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each hosted site corresponds to a different IP address, you can specify the binding IP in VisualSVN Server properties. In this way, VisualSVN Server will be listening on this specific IP and will not respond on requests for other addresses (i.e. hosted sites). In other words, 443 port will be available for other addresses.

To specify VisualSVN server binding address :

- use 'VisualSVN Server Manager'
- right-click on your server
- go to 'Network' tab
- in 'Server Binding' section, check 'These IP addresses' and add the right address

If your hosted sites and your VisualSVN Server are reachable via the same IP address, I think you will have to change VisualSVN listening port from 443 to another port number (in Network tab; dont forget to restart VisualSVN server). The only drawack is that you will have to specify explicitly the port number in URL's to reach the SubVersion Repositories login page : https://your-domain:NEW_PORT_NUMBER/svn/

Comment: The first suggestion of binding VisualSVN Server to a specific IP didn't work for me. It continues to listen on port 443 for all IPs. Your second suggestion worked a treat though.

Answer (score 1):

That means the VisualSVN Server serves all https connections (port: 443). May be you should configure a virtual host on the VisualSVN Server instead.